# NLP always returns sentiment as -1

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

NLP library always returns sentiment integer as -1

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.neural.rnn.RNNCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;

public class NLP {
    static StanfordCoreNLP pipeline;

    public static void init() {
        pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP("MyPropFile.properties");
    }

    public static int findSentiment(String tweet) {

        int mainSentiment = 0;
        if (tweet != null && tweet.length() > 0) {
            int longest = 0;
            Annotation annotation = pipeline.process(tweet);
            for (CoreMap sentence : annotation
                    .get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
                Tree tree = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.AnnotatedTree.class);
                int sentiment = RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(tree);
                String partText = sentence.toString();
                if (partText.length() > longest) {
                    mainSentiment = sentiment;
                    longest = partText.length();
                }

            }
        }
        return mainSentiment;
    }
}
```

No matter what sentence i pass it always returns as -1.
Example : "Google is good" returns -1
          "Google is bad" returns -1

Comment: What does your properties file look like?

Comment: annotators = tokenize, ssplit, parse, sentiment

Comment: Did my answer solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change this line

```
Tree tree = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.AnnotatedTree.class);
```

to this

```
Tree tree = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentAnnotatedTree.class);
```

Now it should work.

Comment: Worked, had issues with the jars version :D